# What pool of characters do MD5 and SHA have?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, sha

Does MD5 and SHA only contain alphanumeric characters? (i.e., from A to Z and 0 to 9, or do they exclude some characters?)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

MD5 and SHA hashes in raw form are binary, however their common representation is a hex-encoded string, which contains characters `[a-fA-F0-9]`.

So if this is what you meant, then characters G-Z, g-z are "excluded".

Another, less common, representation is Base64 encoding [0-9a-zA-Z+/].

Comment: Yeah the hex form is what I what mean. Thanks.

Comment: It's common, but not single. Unix password files, for example, contains hashes in Base64 format [0-9a-zA-Z+/].

Comment: Shouldn't an equal sign (`=`) also end up there? In base64?