# How to create a Firestore safe Document ID based on a string

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After some discussion on my question about base64 not being safe for Firestore IDs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273672/is-base64-a-good-option-for-encoding-custom-document-ids-for-firestore?noredirect=1#comment99189620_56273672) I would like to know how one can encode a string to a Firestore "safe" Document ID.

Here is the problem:

- I am login in users via a custom authentication service.
- That service provides a username that **can contain `/`** that are **not safe for the firestore document ids** as declared [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits)

I asked about the base64 in another question and that is not safe as it contains `/`

So what could be a safe way to encode that string without loosing the entropy of the username that the external service provides. That means that there could be a username such as `dimi/test1` and another as `dimitest1` so just stripping out characters is not an option.

Also since that service has available an open API and my service exposes the document ID's via URLs I would like not to expose the other service usernames via my apps URLS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask why you want (as user) to generate the ID? Firestore already have a unique safe ID generator and Firebase Auth as well, any of those should give you unique IDs for your necessities.

Comment: @IgnacioBustos 

I am adding in a queue items that I need access without quering. 

So if I can always build the same id I can access that faster and with less reads/writes. 

Imagine that is an API service / function that gets about 100K calls per day. 

Does this help?

Comment: @IgnacioBustos Additionally this way I wont every insert a duplicate queue item. 
The input I get from API calls is : USERNAME/WORKOUTID.

Comment: @IgnacioBustos You can also consider it as a  Mapping to each service's users workout. 

So even if the user on that service updates the info, the same queue item is updated and leter on consumed

Comment: oh, I get that, very expensive to call Firebase for this. So let me assume more things and correct me if not. So 'userID' (A) & 'workoutID' (B) is known, isn't it? in that case, your new relationalDB can be `${userID}${workoutID}` without any slash `/` in it. In case you dont know the IDs beforehand, I have another approach to generate IDs by yourself fast and reliable, but its mandatory to use Node.js for security reasons. Let me know and I will write to you the approach.

Comment: I added a reply directly in case you need to generate completely the IDshttps://stackoverflow.com/a/62775792/1240074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

In order to transform strings into uniqueIDs very fast use `crypto.createHash()` instead. The result will be the same for a given string input.

You can use MD5 or SHA256 as both takes the same time, 2.2s average to calculate 1 Million unique IDs.

Here is the code:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function uniqueId(string, algorithm = 'md5') {
  return crypto.createHash(algorithm).update(string).digest('hex');
}

console.log('started');
console.time('generateIDsMD5')
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  uniqueId('a string ' + i);
}
console.timeEnd('generateIDsMD5');

console.time('generateIDsSHA256')
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  uniqueId('a string ' + i, 'sha256');
}
console.timeEnd('generateIDsSHA256');

// For instance, It will take around 2.2s average
// to generate 1Million Unique IDs with MD5 or SHA256 encryption

console.log('MD5 string ', uniqueId('a string ' + 1));
console.log('MD5 sameString ', uniqueId('a string ' + 2));
console.log('MD5 sameString ', uniqueId('a string ' + 2));
console.log('SHA256 string ', uniqueId('a string ' + 1, 'sha256'));
console.log('SHA256 sameString ', uniqueId('a string ' + 2, 'sha256'));
console.log('SHA256 sameString ', uniqueId('a string ' + 2, 'sha256'));
console.log('finished');
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I adapted the code from Firebase and made it available directly on your node.js with some custom test for you. It takes up to 3s for 1 Million IDs, and only 300ms for 100.000 IDs which is your considered daily usage approach.

This uses `crypto` considered very safe if run in node.js environment.

here is the function wrapped with usage example:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function autoId(bytesLength) {
  const chars =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let autoId = '';
  while (autoId.length < bytesLength) {
    const bytes = crypto.randomBytes(40);
    bytes.forEach(b => {
      // Length of `chars` is 62. We only take bytes between 0 and 62*4-1
      // (both inclusive). The value is then evenly mapped to indices of `char`
      // via a modulo operation.
      const maxValue = 62 * 4 - 1;
      if (autoId.length < bytesLength && b <= maxValue) {
        autoId += chars.charAt(b % 62);
      }
    });
  }
  return autoId;
}

console.log('started');
console.time('generateIDs')
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  autoId(20);
}
console.timeEnd('generateIDs');
// For instance, It will take around 3s average
// to generate 1 Million Unique IDs with 20 bytes length

console.log('example 20bytes ', autoId(20));
console.log('example 40bytes ', autoId(40));
console.log('example 60bytes ', autoId(60));
console.log('finished');
```

Simply use `node thisfile.js` and you will see your result.

Since firebase is mainly open source we can find the official uniqueId generator used in `node.js` to generate the IDs here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/4f4574afaa8cf817d06b5965492791c2eff01ed5/dev/src/util.ts#L52

**IMPORTANT**

If you are going to join 2 IDs, do not use any slash `/`, as you know it is not allowed, instead use underscore `_` or nothing at all since you have control of the length of an ID, therefore you should know how to split the ID accordingly (40 bytes contain 2 IDs of 20 bytes for instance).

The limitation of firestore in Document Ids is 1500 bytes so you have plenty to play with.

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits

Comment: I know you took some time to write this and for that I ll be awarding you for sure. 
However (And answering the comment as well) , I get the ids from others (API). 
`${userID}${workoutID}` would not work as the URI later on can be exposed. One could use those (From a shared URI). 

So I would like those to lets say: "Base58?" Crypto? 

So 2 inputs (USERID, WorkoutID) should give a unique Firestore ID. 

I think (from what I understand) this answer does not do it right ? 

I appricate you took the time to teach me how to create IDS (and will use it) but those are given :-/

Comment: To be a little more helpfull maybe: https://github.com/jimmykane/quantified-self/blob/master/functions/src/queue.ts#L74 

See how a queue item is inserted.

Comment: Ok I see, so you want the `generateIDFromParts` to generate the same string while the input is the same, no matter how much you call the function again with the same input?

Comment: Correct! Now I base58 encode. According to my research should be fine but I am scared about collisions etc. Also my own answer is downvoted so it starts to smell if you get my point.

Comment: you can pass both Ids concatenated like `uniqueId(\`${userID}${workoutID}\`)` to get the same result always

Comment: you can also digest the hash in a different way to get more complex unique results like 'utf-8', more info https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings

Answer (score 2):

Use encodeURI() followed by SHA256. This will constraint the document ID to

> ```
> Must be valid UTF-8 characters
> Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
> Cannot contain a forward slash (/)
> Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
> Cannot match the regular expression __.*__
> ```

encodeURI is for valid UTF-8 characters.

SHA256 is fixed length at 256 bits (or 32 bytes) therefore not exceeding 1,500 bytes limit.

SHA256 characters are [a-fA-F0-9] according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618366/3073280.

Lastly, you mentioned that it will need entropy. SHA256 is well diffused.

Comment: Its 1m records in each call. Wont SHa256 require more CPU and why not Base58?

Comment: How about ` new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(message);` in regards to URF-8 ?

Comment: Why not simply use encodeURIComponent('dimi/test1')?

Comment: @harsh989 some characters are not escaped in encodeURIComponent.

Answer (score -1):

I used Base58 and that was the most safe I could research for

Comment: why not use hash e.g. SHA256? It is fixed-length and its characters pool are `[a-fA-F0-9]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12618366 while preserving the entropy.